# Reduce left margin for menu item of Navigation drawer?

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer, menu-items

I am using a custom menu in a navigation drawer. I would like to only reduce the left margin of the menu items and move the image view a little closer to margin (towards the left). I have already made the dimension changed for reducing the bottom margin and move the image view and text view.

```
<!-- Override the private variables in navigation drawer-->
    <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size">45dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_icon_padding">5dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_navigation_seperator_left_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

[image]

I would only like to reduce the 16dp space for the image. Is there any dimension variable that can be over-ridden to do this ?

NavigatonView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@null"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle">
```

I have added

```
tools:override="true"
```

in the DrawerLayout.

The menu_drawer looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:id="@+id/grp1" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_home_unselected"
            android:title="Home" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp2" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_identify"
            android:title="Identity" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/grp3" android:checkableBehavior="single" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_item_3"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_self_disclosure"
            android:title="Disclosure" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant xml files, most importantly the drawer / navigation view ones.

Comment: It's updated in the question now.

Comment: @USKMobility : The question you shared reduces the spacing at the bottom between the menu items. I am looking to reduce the space between the left margin and the menu item. I have also added the dimension changes mentioned there in my question too.
I have the `<item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">18dp</item>` in my styles file too.

Comment: define listPreferredItemPaddingLeft in your style same way and try

Comment: @USKMobility it worked ! :) Awesome answer. Can you make this as an answer ?